# Is the intersection of connected open balls connected?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $x,y\in X$ and $\delta, \varepsilon>0$. If $B_\varepsilon(x)$ and $B_\delta(y)$ are connected, must $B_\varepsilon(x)\cap B_\delta(y)$ be connected?

I think  that $B_\varepsilon(x)\cap B_\delta(y)$ must be connected, but I'm struggling to prove it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the unit circle $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2: |x|=1\}$ with the arc metric. If you take balls centered at $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ which intersect but are not the whole circle, then their intersection is disconnected.

Comment: Sorry if the question is too basic but, how is the arc metric defined?

Comment: It's the length of the arc connecting the points.